# Contextual GWT Gadget and RPC Servlet on Google App Engine

Tags: rest, google-app-engine, gwt, google-api, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I'm a newcomer in contextual (gmail) GWT gadgets. 
The idea is to show in gmail gadget some info from external web service(REST).

I think that my app should consists of 3 parts:

1. UI. Gadget byitself with labels and other control
2. Servlet. It should communicate with gadget via RPC
3. WebService which should interact with Servlet.

I successfully created parts 1 and 2. 
So I have an RPC communication between 1 and 2. And this is a contextual gadget already.
Now I'm stuck with the problem how to get the user on the server side (in servlet).
I tried:

```
UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
userService.getCurrentUser().getNickname();
```

but this doesn't work.

My gwt and servlet are hosted at Google Apps Engine.

Answer (score 0):

it seems the problem is in making the servlet on GAE communicate with gadget. [here is an answer from google employee](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/apps-apis/thread?tid=473370c6d4be61f1&hl=en) that may help you.